# how to modify service provider SAML2 Web SSO Configuration

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, server, identity, saml

WSO2 IS: 5.0.0 with service pack
documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0

I added the travelocity.com service provider according the document. 
run http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com and got authentication error. So I tried to check and modify inbound Authentication Configuration > SAML2 Web SSO Configuration, all I see is "Configure" link. Click the link, it shows "New Service Provider" page with "Register" and "Cancel" buttons. If I click Register button, I got duplicate service provider error. Does the UI support modifying SAML2 Web SSO Configuration?

I then deleted the Service Provider and add the travelocity.com service provider from scratch. However, I got duplicate service provider error too when I configure 'SAML2 Web SSO Configuration'

I am stuck. How can I get rid of duplicate service provider error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably,  you may have configured an another SAML2 SSO configuration with same `issuer` name.  You can browse the registry and go to the `/_system/config/repository/identity/SAMLSSO` location and delete the SAML2 SSO configuration that can be found there.  Then retry again.

If not, you can try with some other `issuer` name and see..  As in [doc](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/),then you need to provide a new issuer name in the travelocity.com application.

`SAML.IssuerID=travelocitynew.com`

Then in the SAML2 SSO configuration of the WSO2IS, you can create the configuration with new issuer name which is `travelocitynew.com`

If you try with fresh WSO2IS SP1,  we can not see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The document missed one step: click 'Update' button to save whole configuration after clicking Register button new SAML2 Web SSO Configuration. Anyway, I believe it still a bug in the web console of WSO2IS.

What I did is to reinstall WSO2IS+service pack from scratch and configure it again.